# Angular 2 *ngIf statement with multiple values

Tags: typescript, angular

Maybe an outdated question but I cant get it to work.

I have an `*ngIF` statement and i want to use multiple conditions like this:

```
*ngIf="expression && prototype?.valueType === 'Integer' && 'String'"
```

How do I set this `*ngIf` with multiple conditions?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This usually works fine.

The expression

```
*ngIf="expression && prototype?.valueType === 'Integer' && 'String'"
```

seems a bit off.

Perhaps you want something like

```
*ngIf="expression && (prototype?.valueType === 'Integer' || prototype?.valueType === 'String'")
```

Comment: Trying to check like `*ngIf="projectId!==undefined && projectId!==null && projectId!==''"` doesn't throw any errors but doesnt seem to work too. Can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Please create a Plunker that allows to reproduce. Shouldn't `*ngIf="projectId"` be sufficient?

Comment: Yes, it should be enough. The above was a desperate test. Yet it doesn't work like expected. I'm not able to create a plunker because that would ask me to create allot of files like services and models (I don't know how to setup the plunker without them) but I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with a lot of files like ... Plunker provides a ready-to-use Angular2 template. If it's about your custom code, I doubt it's related to the `*ngIf` expression when you think you need a lot of services and models to reproduce.

Comment: That's because you didn't start with the Angular template provided by Plunker.

Comment: getting error with multiple args as you mentioned above but getting error: Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with *

Comment: I don't think your error is related to my answer. Sounds like you have `*ngIf="..." *ngIf="..."` or `*ngIf="..." *ngFor="..."` or similar. You can't have to directives with `*xxx` on the same element as the error says.