# Output from nested child to parent to grand-parent component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, input, output

Hi angular community !

My issue is that i am tried to fired the child output to say the gran parent that the child is open or close but the parent could also fired the child and output it same way, it a bit like that post plus the gran parent [How to use @output to fire a boolean from child to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323052/how-to-use-output-to-fire-a-boolean-from-child-to-parent/45323079#45323079)
PS: Note that the child could be fired/hide from the parent and the gran parent..thanks for help and if it's not clear don't hesitate to ask me for details..

gran parent.html:

```
<div class="daydetail">
 <img src="./assets/img/fold_down_black.png" class="clickdaydetail" type="button" label="Click"(click)="toggleChild()"/>
 <div><my-daydetail [showMePartially]="showVar"(close)="isHidden = true" (open)="isHidden = false"></my-daydetail></div>
  <div [hidden]="isHidden" >

     <div><app-pie-chart [minifiedMe]="showVar" ></app-pie-chart>
</div>
    <div><app-fonctionnaly [minifiedMe]="showVar"  ></app-fonctionnaly></div>
  </div> <!-- Fin de isHidden -->
```

parent.html:

```
<div *ngIf="showMePartially" class="daydetail2" > <!-- this part will be toggled by the parent component button  -->

 <img type="button" label="Click" (click)="hideDem()" id="foldup" src="./assets/img/fold_up_blacksmall.png"/>
  <span id="infonc">Informations sur le fonctionnement</span>
</div> <!-- Fin de daydetail2 -->
 <p class="taux2">Taux de fonctionnement sur la période</p>
 <img type="button" label="Click" (click)="hideDem2()" src="./assets/img/fold_up_blacksmall.png"/>
<app-my-verticalchart [showMePartially2]="showVar" (closed)="isHiddenn = true" (opened)="isHiddenn = false"></app-my-verticalchart>
```

parent.ts

```
@Input() showMePartially: boolean;
@Input() showMePartially2: boolean;
@Output() open: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Output() close: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Output() opened: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Output() closed: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

child.html

```
<div *ngIf="showMePartially2" class="chart2">

     <chart [options]="options" (load)="saveInstance($event.context)">
      <!--    <point (select)="onPointSelect($event)"></point> -->
      </chart>
<!--  <p><b>{{point}}</b><p> -->
</div>  <!-- ================ Fin de chart2 ================ -->
```

child.ts

```
 @Input() showMePartially2: boolean;
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36722605/angular-2-ngif-statement-with-multiple-values

Comment: @Val it's not the same my question but mine is also about property bindings and binding a component from two different parents, maybe should I update my title?

Comment: @EmileCantero, code looks bit messy and also not syntactically true , will you please explain bit better ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi Ahright first thanks for your question. I've got a parent compoent where a want to fire a child, but I want this child the possibility to be fired (and close) from an other parent (each parent got him own button) is that more clear?

Comment: @Vega as you can see my code already use the Input decorator

Comment: I edited my post with a lots of more infos